# How to make array values all capital letters lazarus

Tags: arrays, listbox, lazarus, uppercase

The user inputs string values into a string array via an InputBox, once the values are stored, how do I make all the letters become capital letters only, such as the example below. These values must then basically overwrite the non-capitalized values within the array so that they can be displayed within a listbox later. I know that i need to use the UpperCase function but i can't seem to get it to work correctly as it appears non-capitalized again.

This is my first time experimenting with arrays and the UpperCase function so please be nice.

Example : 'Hockey', 'Tennis', 'Football'
     to   'HOCKEY', 'TENNIS', 'FOOTBALL'

UpperCase Code:

```
procedure TFrm2016Assignment9.BtnCapitalStrClick(Sender: TObject);
   var
       Capitalise : string;
begin
 Capitalise := UpperCase(nBasicsStrArray[0]);
end;
```

Display Code:

```
procedure TFrm2016Assignment9.BtnDisplayStrClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dDateTime := Date() + Time();
  LstOutput.Items.Add('String Array : ' + DateTimeToStr(dDateTime));
  LstOutput.Items.Add(nBasicsStrArray[0]);
  LstOutput.Items.Add(nBasicsStrArray[1]);
  LstOutput.Items.Add(nBasicsStrArray[2]);
  LstOutput.Items.Add(nBasicsStrArray[3]);
  LstOutput.Items.Add(nBasicsStrArray[4]);
  LstOutput.Items.Add('****');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

`UpperCase` is a function that returns a new value with letters made upper case. It does not modify its argument. You assigned this new value to a local variable and immediately forgot it.

Remove the `BtnCapitalStrClick` method that serves no purpose. When you add the strings convert them to upper case:

```
LstOutput.Items.Add(UpperCase(nBasicsStrArray[0]));
```

Comment: I've decided to take this approach but as per my assignment I have to keep the BtnCapitalStrClick method, so what ive done is i've made this method not only capitalize the array items but also to display them at the same time. So LstOutput.Items.Add(UpperCase(nBasicsStrArray[iCount])); - within a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Lazarus topic it should be noted that the UpperCase solution is only correct for the first 128 ASCII characters. Lazarus uses UTF8 encoding by default, and therefore fhe function UTF8Uppercase (in unit LazUTF8) is a more general solution because it considers all characters.

Comment: This should really be a comment since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I believe they've made that more generic now. Generally, use the functions normally, and, certainly, test the code with some foreign characters.

Comment: No, just checked with Laz-trunk and fpc-trunk (a bit outdated, though) : UTF8Uppercase still required.

Comment: You didn't answer the question though. Please convert this to a comment.

Comment: How to convert to a comment?

Comment: Add a comment, and then delete this post

Comment: And the responses to the original text?

Comment: If you want to keep the info then write it as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

What data type is nBasicsStrArray?

Just use UpperCase on the whole string:

```
whatever := UpperCase(someEdit.text);
```

Comment: The array's data type is also String.